# Articles in conjuctions

Tags: grammar, articles, conjunctions

The following is taken from a book:

> As a result, hosting in IIS 5/6 is notorious for instability and the frequent need to reset the server or IIS 5/6.

In the context above, why doesn't "instability" have an article, while "frequent need" does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The instability* would point to a definite, previously defined instability.

On the other hand, omitting the article would express that hosting in IIS 5/6 just introduces *all kinds of instability*, or *instability in general*. It might show up differently all the time, the system is just instable. Therefore no definite article.

Using an indefinite article, like *notorious for an instability*, would point to just one kind or instance of instability that would be further defined in the text following.

So the sentence tells you:

> As a result, hosting in IIS 5/6 is notorious for instability in general.

As for *the need to reset*, *the need* is defined and is a singular need, the need to reset.

All this does not depend on the conjunction. You could omit either of the two phrases with no change.